# Designing a Web Interface for a RESTFUL API

Tags: jakarta-ee, web

I am new to Web Page Designing.I am using Struts2 framework for the same.
There is a RESTFUL API implemented for the same which will perform all the tasks for client(web interface).
I have to design the web interface which will contact the user-agent.
Interface which I will be designing will be interacting with the API (user agent) and responses from the agent will be displayed to the client.In short API handles all the activities at the back end.
I did not find any resource on the internet helping me how I could do this.
Links or references would also help me solve this problem and help me get started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Struts2 to access a REST API (I have used other clients), but apparently there is a REST plugin for Struts2 designed to make it easier.  See: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html

Comment: @Soham : you should accept answers if it solves your problem. If it is helpful, then you should upvote(this requires atleast 15 reputation points)